# Fontawesome doesn't work, the icons aren't shown

Tags: html, font-awesome

The problem is that my website aren't shown the Icons. I am a starter and I don't see some error there.

Here is the Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and here I tried to use icons:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>
                <span class="title">Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

That is not the full code but I think it should display an icon.

Comment: That's unrelated to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fas` variant [doesn't exist in that library](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/home). Use `fa`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" ntegrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span>
                <span class="title">Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```